# How to replay recent Influx queries

Tags: sql, influxdb

I want to load test Influx, how do I replay the recent queries that were executed? I have not found anything meaningful on Google.

Answer (score 0):

You can get queries with:

```
docker logs $MYCONTAINER --since "10m" |& grep -o -P "query=\K.+" | sed 's/^.//;s/.$//' > out.txt
```

And then execute them with:

```
cat out.txt | xargs -I _ docker run -t --rm influxdb:1.8-alpine influx -host MYHOST -port 8086 -username USER -password PASS -database DB -execute _
```

To measure the time spent for each query, on the influx box you can run

```
sudo strace -p $(pgrep influxd) -f -e write -t -s 512 |& grep "write(1,"
```

Explanation:
`strace` listens for syscalls.

- `-f` flag finds and hooks into any child processes.
- `-e` listens to specific syscalls
- `-t` shows timestamps
- `-s` sets the numbers characters to display

With `grep`, we want to avoid the network syscalls, so we only look at the `stdout` file descriptor.